# Scroll drag on Safari, what's that?

Tags: javascript, html, prismjs

Open the following on Safari and Chrome or Firefox.

https://prismjs.com/plugins/data-uri-highlight/

Now scroll right/left on the code sample. Did you notice it? Kind of a drag? What is that?

Is it a thing of prismjs? I mean, where should I change something to have same behavior on Safari as it is on Chrome/Firefox?

Here is what I did:

(I'm trying to make a source code visualizer. Similar to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50866/view-multiple-pdf-side-by-side. I haven't seen anything like it before, have you? Features: 1. Side by side visualization of many files with horizontal scroll. 2. Per file independent vertical only scroll.)

[image]

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="prism.js"></script>

<div id="content">

  <div id="left">
    <pre class="line-numbers" data-src="main.cpp"></pre>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <pre class="line-numbers" data-src="main.cpp"></pre>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`style.css`

```
#content, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: intrinsic;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: intrinsic;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Width depends on the content (i.e. `main.cpp`).

Comment: Set a fixed width, and then just use `overflow-x: auto` in your CSS.

Comment: I've given more info on the question, I can't make width fixed because it depends on the content.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "kind of a drag"? That's just the way the browsers have decided to implement scrolling? Apple decided to put more bounce effect into it than Google and Mozilla.

Comment: I'm not familiar with web dev, bounce might be the key word I didn't know about. Is it possible to control this bounce on Safari?

Comment: This is indeed a browser *feature*. What you might want to do is to set a `{position:fixed; width:300vw; height:300vh; z-index:-1; left: -100vw; top:-100vh; background:#your_background_color#;}` div so that it doesn't default to white and be less visible. http://jsfiddle.net/t93fvpw7/

Comment: Didn't understand the idea, but color isn't the point. And since you mentioned fixed width/heigh it smells to me something else also.

Comment: It's often called elastic or momentum scrolling, and there are several questions about disabling it in Stack Overflow, you will find them by searching for said terms. And note that if you decide to disable that somehow, it's probably going to affect iOS devices in a multitude of ways depending on the iOS version. In any case, it's going to be more of a hack than a proper solution.